# How can we prove that $\mathbb R P^n \to \mathbb R P^n/\mathbb R P^{n-1}$ induces isomorphism on $H_n$ when n is odd?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is said that $\mathbb R P^n \to  \mathbb R P^n/\mathbb R P^{n-1}$ induces isomorphism on $H_n$ when $n$ is odd. How can we prove this?

Comment: Compute the cellular homology groups of both, check they're isomorphic.  Look at the proof that cellular homology computes singular homology and see that it implies exactly what you want.